# Other targets don't update the target specific variable for a base target

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

Using the flowing make file:

```
ODIR = obj
_OBJ = hello.out
OBJ = $(patsubst %,$(ODIR)/%,$(_OBJ))
dir_guard=@mkdir -p $(@D)

echoit: $(OBJ)
    @echo $(BAR)


target: ODIR=obj/debug
target: OBJ = $(patsubst %,$(ODIR)/%,$(_OBJ))
target: echoit

$(ODIR)/hello.out:
    $(dir_guard)
    touch $@

clean:
    rm -rd obj
```

When I call

```
make target
```

I get a file in obj/hello.out not obj/debug/hello.out as I expected.  Any Ideas what I'm missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$(OBJ)` in the `echoit` rule is expanded when the makefile is first parsed by make; target-specific variables are for use in **recipes**, not rules, as the manual [points out](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Target_002dspecific)

> As with automatic variables, **these values are only available within the context of a target’s recipe** (and in other target-specific assignments).

I'm not exactly sure what you are trying to accomplish here, but it appears you were looking for something like

```
target: $(_OBJ:%=obj/debug/%)
```